# How can I remove lines from a file without loading it all into memory

Tags: node.js

I'm using bunyan to log some stuff and want to remove logs older than a certain date. The question is, can I remove the lines without loading the entire file into memory and parsing it?

My first thought was to just read line by line and copy the required lines into a new file, then rename the new file + delete the old one but this just feels hacky. Is there a better, more straightforward way to do it?

Comment: I think the only way to do it is what you suggested: Copy line by line the lines you want to keep into a new file and delete the old one. There's no mechanism I know to simply "remove a line" from a file.

Comment: Why do not you use log rotation? P.S. If you're on Linux - you can use the `split` command to cut the file into pieces.

Comment: @stdob-- there are other scripts/apps that read these logs and I can't readily change them to handle rotations. It is an option tho, thanks for the suggestion.